# Store a user defined object in a cell in MS Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, arrays, base64, apache-poi, zipoutputstream

I have a user defined object that needs to be stored in a cell for each row.

As of now I store the value as a String using the below process,
  (1.) Convert Object to byte[] - Using ByteArrayOutputStream
  (2.) Convert the byte[] to String - using Base64 Encode.
Again I am reading the stored value as,
  (1.) Convert String to byte[] - Using Base64 Decode
  (2.) Convert byte[] to Object - Using ByteArrayInputStream

This works fine for me, but the size of the Excel increases from 800KB to 1.1MB(for instance). So to reduce file size further, I used ZipOutputStream to zip the byte[] value and then converted to String using Base64 Encode. But this further increase the size of the file to 2.2MB. So I think the Base64 Encode increase the size of the file, if I am processing a zipped byte[] value.

Kindly let me know if I am doing something wrong here/ if there is any better option to store the object into excel cell.
P.S. I will be reading and using the stored object for further purpose.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: What value does a BASE64 coded byte representation (of an object) in an Excel file have? I don't see any. So the next question is: Why Excel? Why not simply write the serialized form of that object into a simple file, if you need to read it later?

Comment: (1.)My Object is a complex POJO clasess that contains values like Integer, float, Object etc.,. So I use Base 64 encoding and decoding methods. (2.) It is a part of my requirement in the excel report to store the object and retrieve the same later for evaluation. So i need to store the object in the excel cell.

Comment: Well ... As a professional developer you should question that requirement. It does not make any sense! Ask yourself the question: Which person needs to open or work with this Excel file and read or work with BASE64 coded data?